# Help with cPickle in Python 2.6

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.6, pickle

I tried the following code I python. This is my first attempt at pickling.

```
import Tkinter
import cPickle


root = Tkinter.Tk()

root.sclX = Tkinter.Scale(root, from_=0, to=1500, orient='horizontal', resolution=1)
root.sclX.pack(ipadx=75)



root.resizable(False,False)
root.title('Scale')


with open('myconfig.pk', 'wb') as f:
    cPickle.dump(f, root.config(), -1)
    cPickle.dump(f, root.sclX.config(), -1)
root.mainloop()
```

But get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 244, in run_nodebug
  File "C:\Python26\pickleexample.py", line 17, in <module>
    cPickle.dump(f, root.config(), -1)
TypeError: argument must have 'write' attribute
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I tried the following code, and it works! Now how do I make it so when the program is restarted the scale is in the same position it was when the program was last closed?

```
import Tkinter
import cPickle


root = Tkinter.Tk()

root.sclX = Tkinter.Scale(root, from_=0, to=1500, orient='horizontal', resolution=1)
root.sclX.pack(ipadx=75)



root.resizable(False,False)
root.title('Scale')


with open('myconfig.pk', 'wb') as f:
    cPickle.dump(root.config(), f, -1);
    cPickle.dump(root.sclX.config(), f, -1);
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe mark a question as accepted / move the EDIT into a separate question? Although I doubt you have this problem any more...

Answer (score 2):

Try switching the order of the arguments:

```
cPickle.dump(root.config(), f, -1)
cPickle.dump(root.sclX.config(), f, -1)
```

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html), the file should be the second argument, and the object to be pickled should be the first.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the parameters in the wrong order. See the docs [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/node317.html). Try below:

```
cPickle.dump(root.config(), f, -1);
cPickle.dump(root.sclX.config(), f, -1);
```